# What are the core differences between strawberry varieties?

Tags: strawberries

What are the core differences between strawberry varieties?  (For commercially available strawberries in North America and worldwide0)  For example, strawberries from Oregon and Washington are smaller and redder than those from California, but they don't have as long a shelf life.

(Also, what names - rather than their origin - identify these different strawberries?)

Comment: In my experience local strawberries in general tend to be smaller and to not have the white cucumber-like cores of typical commercial long-distance-shipped strawberries, which require greater resistance to crushing and a greater shelf life.

Comment: There are at least as many varieties of strawberry as varieties of apple. I doubt that a whole state grows only one variety.

Answer (score 4):

I can only answer this for northern europe:
In Europe 'Elsanta' is the variety most grown commercially. Its because it stands up to transportation better then anything else. But its taste is lacking. Given a choise, get something else, even if they look good, which they will.
Grown in Denmark:
Honeyoye - early. taste ok, not great.
Sonata - very good strawberry and its mid season.
Polka - good taste mid season.
Florence - late season. Good taste.

My experience with strawberries is get it locally, always. The great tasting strawberry varieties don't stand up to transportation very well, Its best if they are eaten within hours after picking. If that is not possible I would get strawberries from as cold a climate as possible, because berries in general get more complex flavors if grown under cool condition.